# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)

Tags: java

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SchleifenUebung {
    public void zeilenAusgeben(int Zeilenanzahl) {
        int index = 1;
        while (Zeilenanzahl >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Zeile z" + index);
            index++;
        }
    }

    public void ausgabeQuadratZahlen() {
        System.out.println("Eingabe Grenze:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;
        int n;
        int index = 1;
        do {
            System.out.println("Eingabe Grenze:");
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            n = Integer.parseInt(line);
            index++;
        } while (n >= 1 && n <= 100);

        while (index <= n) {
            System.out.println(n + "^2=" + index * index);
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found at
>   java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)

Comment: Please format your code and ask a question

Comment: public void ausgabeQuadratZahlen()
  {
   System.out.println("Eingabe Grenze:");
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   String line;
   int n;
   int index = 1;
   do
   {
   System.out.println("Eingabe Grenze:");
   line = scanner.nextLine();
   n = Integer.parseInt(line);
   index ++;
   }
   while(n >=1 && n <=100);
   
   while(index <= n)
   {
   System.out.println(n+"^2="+index*index);
   index ++;
   }
   }

Comment: Consider using the question's edit button to add code, and not adding it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you try to scan input until a number between 1 and 100 is entered, but with `while(n >=1 && n <=100)` you do the opposite, and if no number outside that range appears before the end of the input stream, the shown exception arises. Change to `while (n < 1 || 100 < n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, Scanner is proving the method which can convert Inputs directly to int, it can do parsing form your side you don`t have to do it manally

```
  scanner.nextInt();
```